# Server Header showing in IIS 10.0 even after removing Server Header from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

i am getting an issue, Disclosing IIS version at the Server Response Header and Status Code is displaying "302". Can anyone please give me the solution, how to remove Server Header. I have created a IIS rewrite rule for removing the server header.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Comment: Code block and error stack trace will help to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't easily remove the Server header. The best way that I'm aware of is to utilize rewrite rules.

**The following outbound rewrite rule (`outboundRule`) that will remove the `Server` header:**

```
<rewrite>    
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Remove Server header">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this outbound rule is already created in the IIS. I have done VAPT testing for my application. In testing, for one specific URL, IIS version is disclosing and Status code is showing "302". I am trying from couple of days but the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As the Blog mentioned, URL rewrite rules are feasible for `Http.Sys` error. I advise you to remove the server header by using Request filtering. In IIS10.0(Windows2016 above), we can simply remove the Server header by configuring `requrestFiltering` in System.webServer section.

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
</security>
    </system.webServer>
```

By this way, we don’t have to apply the complex outbound rewrite rules, and it still works when the server comes by `HTTP` error.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i have done as you said.  while doing VAPT testing for my application, for one specific URL, IIS version is disclosing.